# How can I have three divs with 33% width and margins fit on one line?

Tags: html, css

I want to put all the 3 boxes in one line but whenever I increase the margin value the third one jumps to the next line. How can I be able to put all of them in one line and make it responsive as per the code below?

The code contains some replication of bootstrap and media queries for large devices. How can I put all three in one line and centered?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
p {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A52A2A;
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
}
.row > div{
    margin: 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-4, .col-lg-6 {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"><p>Item 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"><p>Item 2 Wow this is cool</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6"><p>Item 3</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you make the browser full screen (larger than 1200px)? You have `col-lg-4` on the divs which are 33.33% wide, so three are 99.99% of the screen, but `col-md-6` is 50%. So, 50+50+50=150% which is one explanation as to why it is on a second line, it is larger than 100% of the screen width. Based on your setup, you can only have a total of 12 columns in a single `row` so you need to make sure the sum of the div `cols` equals 12.

Comment: You might also try setting `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:nowrap` on the div that has `class="row"`, and then play around with the `flex-shrink` property on the div's inside of that

Comment: Please remove 
.row>div{
    margin:1px;
}
removing margin will resolve the issue as margin+width may increase space more than 100%, resulting last element to push to next line

Comment: I do want some margin between them. Say, 10px without them moving outside the single line, secondly col-md-6 is for making it responsive i.e. when I reduce the with of the browser, it will go down, that is on purpose, thirdly, I want them to be on the same line when browser is full screen. Adding the margin, is pushing them to the next line, which I don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check if you can change the width attribute to a dynamic attribute like flex

if not you should try using [var()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_var.asp), var() lets you use variables.

make a --margin variable for, well, the margin, then use [calc()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) to calculate what the width should be so the sum of the width and the margin*2 should be equal to 100%/element count.

Comment: `flex` is a value of the `display` property, not the `width` property.

Comment: I know, flex was used as an example of a dynamic attribute, though I do understand how that might confuse someone.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

and remove `col-md-6` and just use `col-md-4` instead.